Getting Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error) when using RecaptchaVerifier on NextJS
Following is my code:
const auth = getAuth(app)

export default function LoginComponent() {

    useEffect(() => {

        if (!auth) {
            return;
        }

        console.log(auth);

        try {
            if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
                window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth,'get-otp', {
                    'size': 'invisible',
                    'callback': (response) => {
                        phoneAuth();
                    }
                });
                window.recaptchaVerifier.render()
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
            createErrorAlertTop("Error initialising phone authentication")
        }

    }, [user,auth])

}

I get the error: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
When I log the auth object, I see an _errorFactor field with an errors sub-field having the message: Another Firebase SDK was initialized and is trying to use Auth before Auth is initialized. Please be sure to call 'initializeAuth' or 'getAuth' before starting any other Firebase SDK.
I have made sure that getAuth() is called before any other firebase service as well in the component. Why is it still throwing an error?
